# Smooth interpolation (and extrapolation) through an approximately periodic function

Tags: python, interpolation, extrapolation, periodicity

I have some data points that I have plotted upon a scatter plot (see below; note that only the blue points are of interest for this question - please ignore the red and green points). These data points exist between -170 and +175 degrees. Firstly, I need to extrapolate over the full range -180 to +180 degrees. How can I do this? Additionally, I want an interpolant which is smooth and not like the cubic interp1d interpolant I currently have in use (light blue curve). That is, there is no necessity for the curve to go through all the scatter points.

[image: graph of curve]

Comment: Can you post the code so your plot is reproducible?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve by adding data you did not measure. One possibility would be to try and perform a FFT on the data to get the separate sinuses and superposition them in a second step. But judging from the amount of Xs in your plot, the amount of datapoint might be to small. With this method, the small hooks (e.g. at (100,-3)) will probably not be resembled.